# Umbraco Multiple fileupload in Admin

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Hi I'm just wondering if there are such plugin available in Umbraco that lets us multiple upload images/files in the Admin panel? I have thousands of files that needs uploading in the admin panel but having it uploaded one by one really takes time and I need to upload this files in just 1 day and I need to do this everyday. I was just thinking of a plugin that can be used? Is there such a thing? Or should I really do a plugin for this?

I'm using Umbraco 7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this already.

Open the media tab and you can upload multiple files

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Didn't notice this. Thanks again